# How can I copy TBitmap memory using with windows CopyMemory function

Tags: delphi, pointers, image-processing

I have 1 bitmap object witdh : 1024px and height : 768 px

I want to cut this bitmap object to 2 part like left and right but I don't want to use DrawBitmap method in canvas because this method can use more CPU then CopyMemory.

I don't want to use this method ( leftImg.Canvas.DrawBitmap(MainBmp, RectF(0,0, MainBmp.Width div 2, bmp.Height),
    RectF(0,0, leftImg.Width, leftImg.Height), 1, True); )

```
MainBmp := TBitmap.Create(1024, 768);

leftImg := TBitmap.Create(MainBmp.Width div 2, MainBmp.Height);
rightImg := TBitmap.Create(MainBmp.Width div 2, MainBmp.Height);

leftBits := PAlphaColorArray(leftImg.Scanline[0]);

CopyMemory(@leftBits[0], @MainBmp.StartLine[0], (MainBmp.Width div 2) * bmp.Height);
```

if I am doing like this he can copy but not left part of bitmap :( he copy half of top to bottom.

That drawing is exactly what I want to do.

[image]

After cut procces, i need like this without using any loop (like while or for)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No can do! As you've found out image data is layout in the memory line by line (hence *scanline*). What you want could only be possible if it was column by column. Without any loops this is not possible.

Comment: @relativ - `CopyMemory` copies a block of memory, and the data you want is in 768 different blocks. No trick will change that.

Comment: Okey I know it thanks :( I just ask it. How can I run that loop process on the GPU? because this is a for some video processing, with CPU this process can take alot of time. Thanks

Comment: @relativ - I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: DrawBitmap probably uses bitblt internally, in which case the work should already be done by the GPU. I don't think you'll be able to speed that up much using a custom implementation unless your graphics driver is very old and/or lame.

Comment: @ 500 - Internal Server Error - thank you so much, yes my development pc is a little bit old but the customer can buy computer with good GPU :) I am doing with DrawBitmap

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, a scanline is a row of pixels, from left to right. There is one scanline for each pixel of vertical height in the image.

Your 1024px x 768px images have 768 scanlines. Copying the first half of the data from scanlines yields you the top half of the image.

You wouldn't have to go through every pixel, you can skip ahead since everything is indexed.

However, since you want both halves, you're not wasting any work by going through the whole thing. As you iterate through the data, copy both the left and right parts out at the same time. So, for the first scanline, copy the first half of pixels to the left image and the rest of the pixels to the right image, go to the next line, and repeat.

This should be less work than DrawBitmap twice.

Also, rather than loading the image, displaying it, then splitting it, split it while you're loading the image.

You'll still need a loop, unless you want to write everything 768 times.

Technically, you could rotate the image and do it the way you want, but rotating it would require loops too, and you'd have to rotate it back when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `TCanvas.CopyRect()` method to copy portions of one `TCanvas` to another `TCanvas`.  It allows the two bitmaps to have different pixel formats.  The OS will handle the differences internally for you:

```
MainBmp := TBitmap.Create(1024, 768); 

leftImg := TBitmap.Create(MainBmp.Width div 2, MainBmp.Height); 
rightImg := TBitmap.Create(MainBmp.Width div 2, MainBmp.Height); 

leftImg.Canvas.CopyRect(
  Rect(0, 0, leftImg.Width, leftImg.Height),
  MainBmp.Canvas,
  Rect(0, 0, leftImg.Width, leftImg.Height)
);

rightImg.Canvas.CopyRect(
  Rect(0, 0, rightImg.Width, rightImg.Height),
  MainBmp.Canvas,
  Rect(leftBmp.Width, 0, rightImg.Width, rightImg.Height)
);
```

Comment: Nice tip. Easier, for sure, if your formats aren't identical, but no performance gain here.

Comment: Is firemonkey canvas have CopyRect method? I am not on pc now but I will check it when I open computer. Thanks

Comment: if performance is an issue, then you have to access the scanlines directly, and you have to either take different pixel formats into account or else normalize the bitmaps to a single pixel format (24 or 32 bit) beforehand.